# Camera to canvas in Mobile App

Tags: javascript, cordova, html5-canvas, cordova-plugins

I am making mobile app which will show `live image of back camera on canvas`. I already tried too many `cordova plugin` but in all of that system app get opened to take picture or video.

Is there any plugin or coding way so I can see live on canvas from `back or front camera`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

JS code

```
// Put event listeners into place
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    video = document.getElementById("video"),
    videoObj = { "video": true },
    errBack = function (error) {
        console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
    };
    // Put video listeners into place
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
        navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
            video.src = stream;
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
            video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    }
    else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    }
}, false);
document.getElementById("snap")
.addEventListener("click", function() {
setInterval(function(){
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
},1);

});
```

notice that a browser supporting the api `getUserMedia` does not mean it can call all cameras on your phone,it is only able to call the front camera probably.

Comment: Thanks for code, but `getUserMedia` dose not work in android < 4.4v.